# startActivityForResult returns to parentactivity instead of the activity itself

Tags: android, image, parent, start-activity, onactivityresult

I have Activity A which starts Activity B and Activity B startsForResult the Galleryapp to pick an image. My Problem is, that when I choose an image (or press cancel) I am returned to Activity A although Activity B started the process and should handle the whole result.

Furthermore Eclipse won't jump into breakpoints anymore after I am returned to Activity A. When I then start Activity B and after that press the button to open the galleryapp again the correct result is returned and everything works perfectly fine.

Can anyone explain to me what's going on here? I was searching quite some time but the only hint I got was, that activity B might have been removed from the stack due to memoryissues. But then why remove activity B and not activity A?.
I really need to get this fixed, so that the galleryapp returns everytime to Activity B when an image was selected.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == btnOk.getId())
    {
        handleOKClick();
    }
    else if(v.getId() == channelThumbnail.getId())
    {
        Intent pickImageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        pickImageIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(pickImageIntent, PICK_IMAGE_RESULT);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_RESULT && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        try {
            InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);

            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            //Set Maximum size of an Thumbnail to 512x512
            bmp = Utility.limitBitmapToBoundries(bmp, 256, 256);
            this.channelThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            this.channelThumbnail.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            AddYamasChannelActivity.this.curSelectedImage = bmp;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }
}

private void handleOKClick()
{
    //Check if Image was already selected, otherwise prompt the user to select an image
    if(this.curSelectedImage == null)
    {
        Utility.showWarningDialog(this, R.string.error, R.string.alertdialog_addyamaschannel_no_image);
        return;
    }

    //Check if Channelname is longer than 3 Characters
    String channelName = et.getText().toString();
    if(channelName.length() >= 3)
    {
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        et.setEnabled(false);
        btnOk.setEnabled(false);
        AddYamasChannelAsyncTask addYamasChannelAsyncTask= new AddYamasChannelAsyncTask();
        addYamasChannelAsyncTask.execute(channelName, googleAccountName);
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(AddYamasChannelActivity.this, R.string.alertdialog_channelname_too_short, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: Are you showing activity A or B in your code?

Comment: My guess is that the Galleryapp returns null in data (which you don't check for) which crashes activity B leaving you with A on top of the stack. Such a crash would also disconnect the debugger (hence no breakpoints in A). Do you see anything in LogCat? Also, if B was removed by the system due to memory issues, B would be recreated when the galleryapp returns (onCreate would run followed by onActivityResult).